# Matlab - Invoking a function handle with generic parameter list

Tags: matlab, function, function-pointers

I'm playing around with numerical integration methods and would like to have a function

```
myIntegrator(f,fParams)
```

In which I'll implement a numerical integration.

As *f* might require any number of parameters, I'm looking for a generic way for *myIntegrator()*  to accept the function handle (@f) and invoke it using *fParams*.

To better clarify,  I would like to call *myIntegrator*, once with  the following *@g* and then with *@h* (just some numerical functions):

```
g(x,y)
h(x)
```

And I'm wondering if there is a single line of code I could use in *myIntegrator* that would perform :

```
myIntegrator(f,fParams)
   invoke(f,fParams)
end
```

and would work both for

```
myIntegrator(@g,[x,y])
```

and

```
myIntegrator(@h,[x])
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `feval`:

```
>> feval(@cos, pi)
ans =
   -1
```

`feval` accepts any number of inputs, which are then given as inputs to the function `f`. In addition, `feval` works for both function handles and functions defined by a string.

A good mechanism to pass on arguments is the `varargin` method, with cell-expansion in the call to `f`, as described by Shai.

However, I would advise you to forget about all this and take another route; *anonymous functions*:

```
[t,y] = myIntegrator(@(t,x) f(a,t,c,x,y), ...)
[t,y] = myIntegrator(@(t,x) g(x,y,z,u,v,t), ...)
```

Integrators (if by that you indeed mean solvers for ODEs; otherwise, they're called quadrature methods) normally only input time `t` and state variable `x` into your differential equation. That's also how you would write it mathematically.

Any other parameters the DE might need (constants, data, filenames, ...) are ***not*** the responsibility of the integrator to pass on; that is the responsibility of the ***caller***. The integrator should not have to know about any specifics of your function, nor have a mechanism that more-or-less duplicates something that's already built-in to MATLAB; it violates the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

This shift of responsibility I'm talking about is accomplished by the simple example I gave above. Have a look at how to use `ode45` for more details, or [this page](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html) which the MATLAB documentation on this matter often refers to.

Comment: Thanks for both the reference of _feval_ and the redirection to the anonymous functions route.

Comment: @OhadDan: I added a link to some documentation on this matter, perhaps that clarifies some things.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [variable number of input arguments](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) `varargin`?

```
function myIntegrator( f, varargin )
%
%
fprintf(1, 'function f got %d arguemnts\n', nargin );
% calling f with its arguments
f( varargin{:} );
```

See the manual on `varargin` for more info.

Now you can call it

```
myIntegrator( @g, x, y );
```

as well as

```
myIntegrator( @h, x );
```

Comment: That's a great suggestions but as my f's and g's may require a fairly varied number of parameters, this could very quickly become very ugly. Thank for the suggestion though!